# How to get access token for one drive API to upload a file?

Tags: java, rest, logic, onedrive

I am creating an application where I want to call API of OneDrive to upload file. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659726.aspx) is the link to page and API I am using is : https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files/HelloWorld.txt?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

I have followed all steps from "code flow" as per link [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm) and got the access token as in response, but it say's 'invalid access token' after using it while running the same API. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45582383/how-to-upload-file-from-local-to-onedrive-account-through-java?noredirect=1#comment78124090_45582383) is screenshot of what I tried. 
I am confused which token to use in that API. Where I can get that ACCESS_TOKEN to run 'upload file' API successfully ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. While running following API , we should add onedrive.readwrite in the scope to upload the file through API.

[Here](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm) are the steps to follow to create access token from 'code flow'.

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={client_id}&scope={scope}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={uri}
```